# How do I get python to import pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, package

I installed Python 3.5.1 from www.python.org. Everything works great. Except that you can't install pandas using pip (it needs visualstudio to compile, which I don't have). So I installed Anaconda (www.continuum.io/downloads). Now I can see pandas as part of the list of installed modules, but when I run python programs I still get:

`ImportError: No module named 'pandas'`

How do I set up my environment to use the modules from Anaconda?

Note: I have Anaconda's home directory and Library/bin on my path, as well as Python's home directory. I do not have PYTHONPATH or PYTHONHOME set, and I know I have the correct privileges to see everything.

Comment: if you open Anaconda, and type `import pandas` does it run?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: @Seekheart If I use the ipython shell in Anaconda, yes, it runs. If I use my other installation, no it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully installed pandas for a Windows 32 bit version Python 3.4 with pre-complied code (no Visual Studio required) using the website:

```
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyyaml
```

There is link for Python 3.5 pre-complied code at this site as well, but I have not tested it.

Download the code you want to a directory on your machine.

Using your Windows CMD.exe, go to your python directory and enter:

```
Python -w pip install "YourDirectory/pandas-0.18.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl"
```

OR

```
Python -w pip install "YourDirectory/pandas-0.18.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Choose the version based on the version of Python you have
have, 32 bit or 64 bit.

Good Luck!

Comment: I tried this, and got the error: `<filename> is not a supported wheel on this platform`

Comment: I needed to upgrade pip, after I did that I could install pandas using this answers instructions. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Anaconda has included one version of Python with it. You have to change your system environment path with Anaconda's instead of the former one to avoid conflict. Also, if you want to make the whole process easy, it is recommended to use PyCharm, and it will ask you to choose the Python interpreter you want.