# AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 're' in pandas Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

I can't import pd from pandas because i have this error. I search on google but I didn't find the fix for this..

```
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 431, in <module>
    re_type = typing.re.Pattern
AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 're'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get python to import pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557174/how-do-i-get-python-to-import-pandas)

Comment: Sir I'm using Python 3.7 but the link you gave is for Python 3.5..
For the mean time I use Python 3.6 to make it work

Comment: do u have the dependencies installed? like numpy?

Comment: Yes I have, I can even import numpy

Comment: This has nothing to do with your pandas installation and everything to do with having a recent enough version of Python so that the typing package has a `re` module.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is changing underneath us as Python's typing module matures, but in our case, the issue was that we did `from Typing import re`, and then later did something like:

```
def funct(some_re: re.Pattern):
```

The fix was dumb. Simply change your import to be `from typing import Pattern` and then do:

```
def funct(some_re: Pattern):
```

Bleh. Warts.